# trying to build a ionic app and get the ANDROID_HOME message

Tags: android, ubuntu, build, path, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build a initial application with ionic and at the moment that I execute the command `sudo ionic build android`, I'm getting the message:

```
felipe@felipe-K46CB:~/ionic/myFirstApp$ sudo ionic build android
Running command: /home/felipe/ionic/myFirstApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/felipe/ionic/myFirstApp
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /home/felipe/ionic/myFirstApp/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/felipe/ionic/myFirstApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/felipe/ionic/myFirstApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

I've checked my ANDROID_HOME and PATH variables:

```
felipe@felipe-K46CB:~/ionic/myFirstApp$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/felipe/andoid-sdk-linux
felipe@felipe-K46CB:~/ionic/myFirstApp$ echo $PATH
/home/felipe/andoid-sdk-linux/tools:/home/felipe/andoid-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/felipe/perl5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

I get the same result if I write `sudo echo $ANDROID_HOME` and `sudo echo $PATH`. These informations are on the .bash_profile and .bashrc file, but this message insist on being shown whenever I try to do the build.

Somebody can help me? I've seen other posts about this problem but none of the solutions is helping me. Can anyone give me any more idea than trying to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while building on my linux machine.

This error is due to the fact that the ANDROID_HOME of the your regular user (the one you log in) and the superuser (the one accessed with sudo) are different, because the $PATHS for each are stored in different files.

i.e the information in the .bash_profile and .bashrc are applied to your user, but when you use sudo it uses the settings for the superuser and thus the $PATH variables are not found.

The below link has a good answer guide on how to add them to the superuser:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/128413/setting-the-path-so-it-applies-to-all-users-including-root-sudo

Myself I preferred setting them manually while building, i.e:

```
    sudo ANDROID_HOME=/home/etobb/eTobb/android-sdk-linux ionic run android
```

and then you can use $ANDROID_HOME freely if you're building with a bash script.